# Code works in one macro but not the other? Using same data set

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running an Excel macro on a csv file.  I have 2 macros and one works on the data set.  I close without saving and run the other macro on SAME data set and I get Excel ERROR - method or data member not found.  What is going on?

I've copied the working code from module that is working to the module that is not, saved and tried again but get same result.

**This works......**

```
Sub Download()

'Download Macro


'Delete All transaction rows from spreadsheet containing "Cash" in Column N
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("N1", ActiveSheet.Range("N999").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("Cash", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

**This is broken**....

```
Sub IRAs_All()

'IRAs_All Macro

'Delete All transaction rows from spreadsheet containing "Cash" in Column N
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("N1", ActiveSheet.Range("N999").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("Cash", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

The correct behavior should be to delete the entire ROW if "Cash" is found in Column N.  It works fine in first module but fails in the second.  I get the following error - method or data member not found - **EntireRow** is highlighted

Comment: I want you to `Debug.Print Activesheet.Range("N999").End(xlUp).Row` and see what value it returns...

Comment: I would also recommend that if you are deleting rows you need to loop from highest row number to lowest row number...

Comment: Dean - I inserted the debug code before statement as never having run debug before wasn't quite sure.  It skipped past the delete row section and then gave me a red duplicate error further below. It looks like while copying from module to module I had a repeat section.  I removed the repeat and recompiled and it solved the problem.  I appreciate your assistance and as a novice if you have anything that gives more on how to debug or troubleshoot in future I will use.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: If you want to address someone in comments, put a @ in front of the user name, for example @Dean - otherwise there will be no notification.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister. @jsmartin722 ALWAYS use `Debug.Print` when building your code as this will allow for you to check things as you build. As such, once your build is complete most of the time you won't run into any problems because you have run your checks along the way. For future reference use `Debug.Print` to check your return values etc and I always use when debugging when something is not adding up! Also leave comments in your code so when you come back in a few months you know exactly what is going on. Likewise if other developers read your code they understand.,